# Getting selenium to work on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5, pythonanywhere

My understanding is that pythonanywhere supports a headless Firefox browser but you need

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
```

And so you can connect using

```
with Display():
    while True:
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(3)
```

And I connect just fine. However, after I start using the driver with

```
with Display():
    while True:
        try:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(3)
    wb=load_workbook(r'/home/hoozits728/mutual_fund_tracker/Mutual_Fund_Tracker.xlsx')
    ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Tactical')

    for i in range(3, ws.max_row+1):
        if ws.cell(row=i,column=2).value is not None:
            driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ws.cell(row=i,column=2).value + '/performance?ltr=1')
            oneyear=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#Col1-0-Performance-Proxy > section > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(5) > span:nth-child(2)').text
            threeyear=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#Col1-0-Performance-Proxy > section > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(6) > span:nth-of-type(2)').text
            fiveyear=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#Col1-0-Performance-Proxy > section > div:nth-of-type(2) > div > div:nth-of-type(7) > span:nth-of-type(2)').text
            ws.cell(row=i,column=10).value=oneyear
            ws.cell(row=i,column=11).value=threeyear
            ws.cell(row=i,column=12).value=fiveyear

           … and so on …
```

I get this error after just a little while

[image]

For what it's worth, this code works perfectly fine on my local machine. Also, I am a paying member, so there should be no whitelist issues.

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: @New contributor Can you see the image okay? I had trouble copying every line at once from the pythonanywhere console.

Comment: It sounds like the browser is crashing; maybe it's something to do with the contents of the page?  What happens if you hit a different URL, say `https://www.google.com/`?

Comment: @GilesThomas You are onto something! Apparently there is a problem with my url; however, entering the url directly into a browser yields a proper webpage. This is what the code resolves to: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/USCBX/performance?ltr=1

Comment: @Giles Thomas While I am a paying member at the lowest tier, do you think I'm still being subjected to the whitelist constraint?

Comment: @Giles Thomas Perhaps just updating the Firefox driver for selenium would solve this?

Comment: I was just about to reply, but I see you've tracked down the problem in your answer below -- have upvoted it :-)

Comment: @Giles Thomas Thanks. I don't think I have much experience with sites blocking certain servers. I ended up getting all information from morningstar without incident. Thanks for helping look into this.

Comment: @GilesThomas Actually, some of the info I still got from yahoo. I learned that if I used `BeautifulSoup` instead of `Selenium`, all was fine. The problem was that some of yahoo's pages are rendered with Javascript, so I really couldn't think of an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has recently come to my understanding that yahoo has blocked pythonanywhere from running any web scraping scripts. I assume this is true for all AWS servers and those who use them, but I am not 100% certain of this. I hope this helps anyone who comes across this question.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/5724/#id_post_52307

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because selenium is unable to connect to the browser you created. If you're running the first chunk of code, and then the second chunk of code, then the display has been close and that would probably cause the browser to crash.

You need to run the code that uses the browser *inside* the with block.

There is an example on the PythonAnywhere help pages that shows how to do all this in the most reliable way.

Comment: But it is all running inside `with Display():`.

Comment: I have updated my question to make this more clear. I do appreciate your response.